# Cassandra : (3.11.11) find a string in the cassandra table column

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am a new bee to Cassandra.

I have a Table(table1) and the Data like

ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4

LD,9813970,1484914,**'T03103','T04014'**

LD,1008203,1486104,**'T03103','T04024'**

Want to find a string in this cassandra table : table1. Is there any option to search a given string in this table's column ch4 using only IN operator (not LIKE operator). Sample query is like

**select * from table1 where 'T04014' IN (ch4)**

if required ch4 column may included in the partition or clustering keys.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the table schema so I'm going to assume that `ch4` is not part of the primary key.

You cannot include a column in the filter unless it is part of the primary key or you have a [secondary index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html) defined on it. Be aware that secondary indexes are not always a good fit. Have a look at [when to use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html) for details.

The general recommendation is to denormalise and create a table specifically designed for each app query so you get the best performance out of your cluster. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your information. First there columns are actually build a primary key.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain it a bit more? Also, please edit your original question and post the table schema so others can understand. Cheers!